# Cracking the Coding Interview 6th Edition, 8.2

Tags: algorithm

Problem States: "Imagine a robot sitting on the upper left corner of grid with r rows and c columns. Robot can only move in 2 directions, right and down, but certain cells are "off limits" such that the robot cannot step on them. Design an algorithm to find a path for the robot from the top left to the bottom right."

My solution was to do something like the following:

```
while grid[r-1, c] !=null && grid[r-1][c] !=false
{
     moveRobotDown();
}
while grid[r, c-1] !=null && grid[r][c-1] !=false
{
     moveRobotRight();
}
```

----after both while loops I'll then throw in a recursive call to the function with the new r,c coordinates.

It seems like a pretty simple implementation, but the answer key has a pretty lengthy and complicated solution. Can anyone explain to me why mine doesn't work?

Comment: When happens if going down as your first move leads you to a dead-end?  Where's your logic to back-track and try another route?

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't work if you had a 'map' like this (where `|` is the path and `*` is where the robot would end up)

```
   |
   |
   |
   *X
   XX
```

The 'robot' would move as far down as possible and then would be unable to move right and your algorithm would fail.

I would recommend reading up on tree traversal, especially [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

Comment: You don't need A* for this problem, since it's dealing with a DAG.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. About 10 lines of code, and time proportional to rows x columns.

Definition: A cell is "fine" if you can reach the bottom right corner from it. In a first pass, you determine all the cells that are fine. Just examine the rows from top to bottom, the columns of each row from right to left: A cell is fine if it is not "off limits", and if it either is the bottom right corner, or if it is above or to the left of a cell that is fine.

If the top left corner is not fine then there is a solution. Otherwise, start with the top left corner. And as long as you haven't reached the bottom right corner, at every turn you go either down or right to a cell that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

try using bfs or dfs. Consider this problem as: shortest path from one point to another.
Using recursion and visited array, that is dfs can resolve this problem quickly.